# Необходимо ли наличие запятой перед именем в подписи?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Разругались с коллегой из-за запятой в подписи письма. Идет текст письма автора, в конце стоит подпись "Твоя дочь Лидия Павлова". Коллега настаивает на знаке, так как, по ее мнению, это уточнение. Я высказываюсь против, потому что не вижу ни обращений, ни уточнений (это как "Твой сын Петр"). Кто из нас прав?

Answer (score 1):

Читаем справочник Лопатина:

> § 63. Нераспространенные приложения обособляются или не обособляются в
>   зависимости от места расположения по отношению к определяемому слову,
>   от наличия или отсутствия при определяемом слове других определений.
>
> 1. Не обособляются нераспространенные приложения, **относящиеся к именам собственным, если стоят перед определяемым существительным**: На шум
>      прибежала из барышниных комнат горничная Дуняша (Купр.).
>
> Примечание.
>   **Рядом стоящие имена собственные и нарицательные могут выполнять разные
>   функции в зависимости от выражаемого значения. Например, в предложении
>   Вошла его сестра Маша приложением является сестра; будучи логически
>   выделенным, слово сестра может стать определяемым, и тогда собственное
>   имя Маша приобретает функцию уточняющего приложения и обособляется**:
>   Вошла его сестра, Маша.
>
> 2. Обособляются (знаками тире или запятыми) приложения, выраженные именами собственными и относящиеся к нарицательным существительным.
>      Такие приложения имеют уточняющий характер и располагаются после
>      определяемых слов: Жене его — Алевтине — не очень хотелось летом в
>      деревню (Шукш.); Обе старшие девочки, Катя и Соня, стали зорко следить
>      за мальчиками (Ч.). То же при уточняющих приложениях, относящихся к
>      личным местоимениям: Он, Саша, не получил почти никакого образования
>      (Ч.).

https://orfhographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120

Так что вы обе правы. Если дочь одна, уточнять нечего, запятой нет, если дочерей много, нужно уточнить, какая именно дочь.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!